# has_archive for default post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

So I have several CPTs set up but I want to have all my default posts listed under /blog.

I was hoping I could somehow enable has_archive for the default post type but I have yet to succeed.

Any ideas?

```
add_action( 'init', 'enhance_post' );

function enhance_post( ) {
    global $wp_post_types;

    $wp_post_types['post']->has_archive = true;
    $wp_post_types['post']->rewrite = array(
        'slug' => 'blog',
        'with_front' => 0,
        'pages' => 1,
    );
}
```

(the above doesn't seem to work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change front page and designate another as blog via *Reading* settings.

See [Creating a Static Front Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page) in Codex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code

```
add_action( 'init', function () {
    $post_type = 'post';
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $post_type);
    $post_type_object->has_archive = 'true';
    $post_type_object->rewrite = array(
        'slug' => '<YOUR_SLUG>',
    );

    register_post_type($post_type, $post_type_object);
} );
```

and in addition to that, you can add rewrite rules to handle that :

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^<YOUR_SLUG>$','index.php?post_type=post','top' );
add_rewrite_rule( '^<YOUR_SLUG>/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$','index.php?post_type=post&paged=$matches[1]','top' );
```

Comment: the first and only technique i found that works !! Thanks !!